# RapidJSON Pointer Set/Create/GetWithDefault causes core dump C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-alignment, rapidjson

I'm running into this error

> Unhandled Fault: Alignment Exception when utilizing RapidJSON
>   Pointers.

I've tried various things with minimal success.

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").GetWithDefault(jsonDoc, "value1");
```

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
if (rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Get(jsonDoc) == nullptr) {
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").GetWithDefault(jsonDoc, "value1");
}
```

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
if (rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Get(jsonDoc) == nullptr) {
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Create(jsonDoc);
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Set(jsonDoc, "value1");
}
```

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
if (rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Get(jsonDoc) == nullptr) {
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Set(jsonDoc, "value1");
}
```

All of the above result in the alignment exception fault (Note: ran into the fault after `Create`, `Set`, or `GetWithDefault` calls. `Get` calls did not cause fault.). The minimal progress made was:

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
if (rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Get(jsonDoc) == nullptr) {
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne").Create(jsonDoc);
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo").Create(jsonDoc);
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Create(jsonDoc);
    rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne/levelTwo/value").Set(jsonDoc, "value1");
}
```

The above successfully made it through the initial Create (`rapidjson::Pointer("/levelOne").Create(jsonDoc)`) before running into the fault.

Any feedback on where I am going wrong in using `rapidjson::Pointer`?

Comment: Any platform/compiler info? I suggest creating an issue in github.